# Understanding crash in Cocos2d iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, crash

I'm trying to understand a crash reported by my crash reporting service. The report is:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS    Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x12341234

0   libobjc.A.dylib    _cache_getImp + 3
2   libobjc.A.dylib    class_respondsToSelector + 30
3   CoreFoundation     objectIsKindOfClass + 36
4   CoreFoundation     __handleUncaughtException + 68
5   libobjc.A.dylib    _objc_terminate() + 128
6   libc++abi.dylib    safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 78
7   libc++abi.dylib    std::terminate() + 19
8   libc++abi.dylib    __cxa_rethrow + 94
9   libobjc.A.dylib    objc_exception_rethrow + 12
10  CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
11  CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
12  GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 74
13  UIKit              UIApplicationMain + 1120
14  MyCocos2diOSGame    
main.m line 6
main
```

The crash reporting service emphasises the following line:

```
3   CoreFoundation     objectIsKindOfClass + 36
```

**What is happening in this crash?**

I'm familiar with the usual crashes like "index out of bounds", "class doesn't respond to selector" etc. However this particular crash baffles me. Line two mentions `class_respondsToSelector` so maybe the code is trying to call a non-existant selector on a class? If that's the case then why isn't the selector mentioned by name?

Any insight is very helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be messaging a deallocated object. Try running with zombies enabled. (Look in your build scheme settings under debugging options). Fishy that the invalid address is 0x12341234

Comment: 0x12341234 looks like an address picked to be obviously invalid, so zombies probably won't help.

Comment: @nielsbot Sure I'll try with zombies enabled. Note the 12341234 is just made up. Tricky part is that I can't reproduce the crash locally.

Comment: So reading this again, it looks like your app hit an unhandled exception, then crashed in the process of terminating. The final crash could possibly be due to messaging a deallocated object or you should have stomped on some memory somewhere. Hard to say without a reproducible case.  You might try adding a crash reporting solution to the next release of your app so you can collect better information.

Comment: You have two problems: 1) You have an uncaught exception. You can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set a handler for uncaught exceptions, so you can see the original exception (and the stack trace that caused it) in the first place. 2) Your app is segfaulting when trying to handle that exception. You are probably using a deallocated instance. It's crashing when trying to determine if an object responds to a selector (not complaining that the object is not responding to a selector, which would be an exception, not a seg fault).