# Objective-c static analysis tool

Tags: objective-c, crash, selector, static-analysis

My crash reporting service is showing a large number of mystery crashes for an iOS app. For a few reasons I suspect the code is trying to perform a selector on an object that doesn't have the particular selector.

**How can I statically analyze the code to find the erronous selector?**

I'm writing Objective-C code using Xcode 4.6 on OS X 10.8. I'm ok with a tool that doesn't pick up things like calling performSelector where the selector is built from a string etc. I think a basic tool will work.

Comment: Unrecognized selector errors are oft caused by memory management issues.

Comment: @bbum Ok thanks for the tip. Do you recommend anything for finding memory management issues in iOS games? I've run the static analyzer and that doesn't report anything memory related. I've run the allocations and leaks tools in Instruments and the output looks fine. I'm asking because a memory management issue would make sense.

Comment: Heapshot analysis is good for detecting memory growth, but a crash like this is *often* (but not always) caused by an over-release.  That can be difficult to track down, especially if all you have a re crash reports from the field.   I'd recommend asking a new question and providing as much concrete evidence as you can (crash reports, etc..).

Comment: So it crashes for other people but you never see crashes yourself when debugging?

Comment: @newacct That's correct. The backtrace is not too helpful either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237357/understanding-crash-in-cocos2d-ios-game. I'm wondering if the crash reporting service reports the OS killing the backgrounded app as a crash.

Answer (score 3):

Select "Analyze" from the "Product" menu in Xcode. Or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

It's invaluable for identifying routine memory management stuff in MRC. But it's still useful for ARC programs.

You might also want to try setting an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) for all exceptions.

I'd also refer you to the [Debug and Tune Your App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1) section of the *Xcode User Guide.* Or Ray Wenderlich's [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) series.

---

By the way, while the analyzer helps, I don't think it will find incorrect selectors. You might want to share how you're using selectors, because it you're using `performSelector`, there are often better patterns. Sometimes you have to use it, but frequently there are other patterns that are more robust. Or if you absolutely need to use selectors, add runtime `respondsToSelector` checks. For example:

```
NSAssert([object respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod:)], @"%@ does not respond to selector someMethod:", object);
```

Or, conditionally perform the selector if it responds to it (this is how you perform a method that might be conditional on a particular iOS version):

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod:)])
    [object performSelector:@selector(someMethod:)];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this however I've tried that and nothing is flagged as a potentially missing selector.

Comment: @SundayMonday If the analyzer flags *anything*, fix it.  Your code should compile with 0 warnings and 0 analyzer issues.

Comment: @SundayMonday Don't use `performSelector` sorts of calls if you don't have to. And if you do, add conditional checks like in my revised answer.